# Wine prevents my system from booting

Tags: 11.04, boot, wine

I installed wine windows program loader in my system having Ubuntu 11.04. I also played certain games with it's help.

The next day when I tried to log into my system I found that my system is struggling to boot. It took almost 20 minutes to get my login screen. Also after typing my password I waited for 10 more minutes for it. I was only able to see the mouse pointer and nothing else.

Now I am using it temporarily with a live USB. I would like to uninstall wine. It is also that I installed wine from Ubuntu software center.

Can anyone suggest me a way out of this?

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt Wine has **anything** to do with your booting issue, the only possibility Wine has of loading anything is after a user logs in.

Anyways, if you want to remove Wine follow the instructions below.

---

Boot up until the login screen, instead of entering your user credentials press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to a TTY (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to switch back to your running X session).

Login in the TTY and use these commands to remove Wine from your system:

*Remove Wine*

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge wine
```

*Move Wine's cache somewhere else*

```
move ~/.wine ~/wine.old
```

*Reboot*

```
sudo reboot
```

That should be enough to remove any Wine traces from your system.

Comment: I tried what you suggested me to do. It says purge not found

Comment: @theja I have just fixed it